# Do I have to invest my Solo 401k contributions to take advantage of tax deferral

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 401k, solo-401k

Is simply contributing to my solo 401k account and keeping it in cash balance enough to take advantage of tax deferral, or do the funds need to be invested?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is simply ... keeping it in cash balance enough to take advantage of tax deferral

**Yes**, because the amount you contribute to the 401(k) is deducted from *this year*'s income (EDIT: he didn't mention Roth), to be paid when you withdraw it many years from now.

**However**, by keeping it in cash, you are:

1. missing out on all that tax <s>free</s> deferred *investment* growth: capital gains, dividends and interest (both reinvested), and
2. **losing to inflation**.

Thus, at the very least invest in high quality (government or corporate) bond funds so as come close to keeping pace with inflation.

Comment: That would be very sad, though, to get to age 65 and realize *foreheadslap* Oh wow, I should've just invested the way university endowments do!  Too bad I didn't know that in 2020!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica good thing OP asked in 2020... :D

Comment: The growth in a nonRoth 401(k) is tax-_deferred_, not tax-_free_.